# SyntaxcError on MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure and ran it, but it is showing some syntax probem, can you help me?

My procedure is as:

```
**DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE TestAdd(
    in mODE varchar(10),
    in Id int,
    in AttName varchar(10),
    in AttValues Varchar(10)
)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AttTable WHERE id=Id) THEN
    SET Mode='Modify'
ELSE 
    SET Mode='Add'
    Start Transaction
    BEGIN
        IF (mODE='Add') THEN
            insert into atttable values (Id, AttName, AttValue);
        ELSE (if Mode='Modify') then
            update AttTable set AttName=AttName, AttValue= AttValue where Id=Id;
        END IF 
    END
$$
Delimiter ;**
```

Comment: You need to tell us how it fails.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is it actually doing? And why is it not formatted to be even the least bit readable?

Comment: also, look into SELECT FOR UPDATE syntax or you'll end up with race conditions

Comment: the whole thing could be made simpler just using the INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax

Comment: @yaauie: You should post that as an answer, it's the Right Solution to this problem... not to mention you deserve some rep for putting in the effort to read that mess :)

Comment: Whenever I am running the Procedure , It is showin some Syntax Error Right to End If.. I fail to Catch It, Your Help would be highly appreciable

Comment: Whenever I am running the Procedure , It is showin some Syntax Error Right to End If.. I fail to Catch It, Your Help would be highly appreciable

Comment: Just replace the whole silly thing with an INSERT statement using the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. Don't mess with writing your own stored procedure to replicate core functionality. I'll let yaauie write up a full answer, since he deserves the credit.

Comment: Thanks to all for your support now I go with Select for Update*,
Still one prob is : can anyone explain me how to use Transactions in Procedures

Comment: There is quite a lot wrong:
 - Missing "Begin" for the procedure
 - Lots of missing semicolons at the end
 - Are you writing mODE and Mode by purpose?
 - Missing "end if" for the first if
 - Maybe "elseif" instead of "else if"

What is the matter with the Transactions? Did you read the manual?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `BEGIN` right after the parameter list at the beginning, and a matching `END` at the end of the procedure:

```
create procedure TestAdd(blah...)
BEGIN
  ...

END$$
```

Your first `IF` call is missing both `THEN` and `END IF`:

```
if exists ( select * from AttTable where  id=Id) THEN
  set...
ELSE
  set...
END IF
```

Each of the statements needs to be terminated with a `;`

```
set Mode='Modify';
set Mode='Add';
Start Transaction;
```

Comment: Are you sure the statements must be terminated with a ;